# Why did cell in org table turn into elisp statement and column TBLFM?

Tags: org-mode, org-table

I've been using org-mode everyday at work for 3 years and recommend that everyone to do the same.

But today, I unintentionally triggered a column function which replaced the cell value with an elisp statement.

- Original Table

  ```
  | Column1 | Column2                                           |
  |---------+---------------------------------------------------|
  | Task1   | Map =LDAPGroupA= group to =ApplicationRoleA= role |
  ```
- Removed `Map + space` from cell

  ```
  | Column1 | Column2                                           |
  |---------+---------------------------------------------------|
  | Task1   | =LDAPGroupA= group to =ApplicationRoleA= role     |
  ```

  Out of habit, did <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>C-c</kbd> to reformat table.
- Result

  ```
  | Column1 | Column2                                          |
  |---------+--------------------------------------------------|
  | Task1   | eq(LDAPGroupA, group to, ApplicationRoleA, role) |
  #+TBLFM: $2=LDAPGroupA= group to =ApplicationRoleA= role
  ```

---

Why did cell in org table turn into elisp statement and column TBLFM?

---

> GNU Emacs 25.2.1 (x86_64-unknown-cygwin, GTK+ Version 3.22.10) of 2017-04-21
>    Org mode version 9.0.9 (9.0.9-elpa)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Why it turns into a `TBLFM`?:
   Because the first char in this field was a `=`, i.e. [column formula](http://orgmode.org/manual/Column-formulas.html).
2. Why turns the field content into an elisp statement?:
   This does not look like a elisp statement, but like a `calc` statement. `calc` is the [default](http://orgmode.org/manual/The-spreadsheet.html#index-calculations_002c-in-tables-333) mode of `org-table` formulas
3. Why turns it into a `equal` statement?:
   Because calc can't resolve the symbols ("LDAPGroupA", "group to", "role") and there is exactly one `=` between every symbol. If you replace the symbols by numbers you get a boolean result (1 or 0).

As wished by comment: example to list item 3:

```
| Column1 | Column2    |
|---------+------------|
| Task1   | =3=3 =3= 3 |

| Column1 | Column2    |
|---------+------------|
| Task1   | =1=1 =2= 1 |
```

after <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>C-c</kbd> in field `(row=2, column=2)` it gets:

```
| Column1 | Column2 |
|---------+---------|
| Task1   |       1 |
#+TBLFM: $2=3=3 =3= 3


| Column1 | Column2 |
|---------+---------|
| Task1   |       0 |
#+TBLFM: $2=1=1 =2= 1
```

Comment: Thanks you for your speedy answer! I think you're very close to the answer. I think you're correct about `calc`. Before I accept your answer, please add an example under `3.` with example I can copy into buffer and test . This example will significantly improve your answer. You are correct that `|=` creates a column formula and likewise `|:=` creates a field formula. However there is an [exception](http://orgmode.org/manual/Emphasis-and-monospace.html) when applying a verbatim format, i.e. `| =verbatim= |`. Any ideas? Thanks again!

Comment: I think that `=` for the formula in a table has a higher priority than `verbatim`. The complete field string after the first `=`is replaced by the result.